# VS Code tasks.json error

Tags: task, visual-studio-code

This is my `tasks.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "clean",
            "windows": {
                "command": "del"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "rm"
            },
            "args": [ "build/*" ],
            "showOutput": "never",
            "isShellCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Every time I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and write `task clean` to execute the task, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'args' of undefined

Does someone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like VSCode isn't satisfied until a `"command"` is specified *outside* of the OS-specific `"linux"` / `"windows"` properties, even if you are on one of these platforms.

With an added dummy `"command": ""`, it works:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "clean",
            "windows": {
                "command": "del"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "rm"
            },
            "command": "",
            "args": [ "build/*" ],
            "showOutput": "never",
            "isShellCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems like a bug to me. I'd recommend you report it to the [VSCode issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).